# Row to cloumn based on where condition - Mysql

Tags: mysql, join

I have table with colimns

### ID|NAME|AGE

1 |name1|40
1 |name2|45
2 |name3|30
2 |name4|39

result i want like this

### ID1|NAME1|AGE1|ID2|NAME2|AGE2

1 |name1|40  | 2 |name3|30
 1 |name2|45  | 2 |name4|39

there are around 5k rows.

Thanks.

Comment: So why bother with MySQL at all?

Comment: Can you provide an example of what you want with more than one row?  The question is not clear in this case.

Answer (score 0):

You can get a full product of the tables:

```
select table.col1,table.col2,table.col3,table2.col1,table2.col2,table2.col3  
from table, table2 
where table.col1='test' and table2.col2='test1'
```

The result may have duplicate records from the both tables. But as you don't have any primary keys that's possibly not an issue for you.

Comment: Not giving desired results